# Different behavior of conditional panels in shinyApp when using do.call(fluidRow, ...)

Tags: r, shiny

This is a bit esoteric, but I am interested in the reason for this strange behavior.

I have a shiny app where I have a checkbox input for the user to select which menus they want to display. For each one they check, an additional "hidden" menu appears. I was interested in doing this programmatically with `do.call` to include an arbitrary number of menus. However, using `do.call` to execute `fluidRow` causes different behavior than calling `fluidRow` directly. Specifically, multiple rows are created instead of a single row, with some unwanted text between each row. Below is a reprex showing this behavior. Can anyone explain why this behavior is occurring and how to fix it?

### Code

```
# Define function to show hidden menu.
hidden_menu <- function(i) {
  column(width = 3,
         conditionalPanel(
           condition = paste0('input.display_menus.includes("', i, '")'),
           checkboxGroupInput(paste0("categories_", i), "Select categories",
                              choiceNames = letters[1:2],
                              choiceValues = letters[1:2],
                              selected = letters[1:2]
           )
         )
  )
}

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Checkboxes of which menus to display
  fluidRow(
    checkboxGroupInput("display_menus", "Select menus to display",
                       choiceNames = c("one", "two", "three"),
                       choiceValues = 1:3,
                       selected = 1:3
    )
  ),
  
  # Menus displayed one way
  fluidRow(
    hidden_menu(1),
    hidden_menu(2),
    hidden_menu(3)
  ),
  
  # Menus displayed another way; shouldn't this be identical to the one above?
  do.call(fluidRow, sapply(1:3, hidden_menu))
  
)

library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = function(input, output) {})
```

### Output

This shows the output with menus 1 and 3 selected. The first way of doing it, calling `fluidRow` directly, works as intended. The second way of doing it, using `do.call`, has a different orientation and some unwanted text output.

[image]

Comment: You have to use `lapply` which returns a list instead of `sapply` which returns a 3 x 3 matrix.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid! I guess I could also have done `sapply(..., simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: Yep, sapply(..., simplify = FALSE) will also do the job. (;